# how to tackle the python set object operations in C?

Tags: python, c, set, ctypes

I want to introduce C code in Python and the C code has the following statements:

- test.h

```
#include<Python.h>

PyObject *getFeature(wchar_t *text,
                     PyObject *unigram);
// where the unigram is a Set Object with type 'PySetObject'
```

- test.c

```
#include<test.h>

PyObject *getFeature(wchar_t *text,
                     PyObject *unigram)
{
    int ret = -1;
    PyObject *featureList = PyList_New(0);

    PyObject *curString = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(text, 2);
    ret = PySet_Contains(unigram, curString);
    printf("## res: `nc`, %d.\n", ret);
    ret = PyList_Append(featureList, curString);

    return featureList;
}
```

and then I compiled it and get a shared lib called `libtest.so`. So I can import this C `.so` file into the python code with `ctypes` like below:

- test.py

```
import ctypes

dir_path = 'path/to/the/libtest.so'
feature_extractor = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(
    os.path.join(dir_path, 'libtest.so'))
get_feature_c = feature_extractor.getFeature
get_feature_c.argtypes = [
    ctypes.c_wchar_p, ctypes.py_object]
get_feature_c.restype = ctypes.py_object

unigram = {'据','nc', 'kls'}
print(hash('据'))
print(hash('nc'))
print(hash('kls'))
res = get_feature_c('nc', unigram)
```

execute this `test.py` file and I can get the following fault:

```
6875335301337518411
6875335301337518411
-5567445891360670268
Segmentation fault
```

I know the bug is caused by **the confliction of different string `nc` and `据`, which have the same hash value** `6875335301337518411`.
Python use a secondary level hashtable to tackle the confliction of strings with same hash value.

So how to solve this problem and import the secondary confliction hashtable to the C code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash match is a red herring.  The problem is not using `PyDLL` so the GIL is held when using the CPython APIs.

**test.c**

```c
#include <Python.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API PyObject *getFeature(wchar_t *text, PyObject *unigram)
{
    int ret = -1;
    PyObject *featureList = PyList_New(0);

    PyObject *curString = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(text, 2);
    ret = PySet_Contains(unigram, curString);
    printf("## res: `nc`, %d.\n", ret);
    ret = PyList_Append(featureList, curString);
    Py_DECREF(curString); // fix reference leak
    return featureList;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.PyDLL('./test') # Use PyDLL so GIL is held
dll.getFeature.argtypes = ct.c_wchar_p, ct.py_object
dll.getFeature.restype = ct.py_object

unigram = {'据','nc', 'kls'}
print(hash('据'))
print(hash('nc'))
print(hash('kls'))
print(dll.getFeature('nc', unigram))
```

Output:

```
5393181648594783828
5393181648594783828
-5015907635941537187
## res: `nc`, 1.
['nc']
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Im still confused about the difference of  cdll.loadLibriary and PyDLL.

Comment: @dongrixinyu `CDLL` (short for `cdll.loadLibrary`) defaults to the "C" calling convention for functions.  `WinDLL` default to "stdcall" calling convention used by Windows APIs.  `PyDLL` calls C functions that use the CPython API, which require the global interpreter lock (GIL) to be held while manipulating Python objects.  If you don't call CPython functions, you don't need it.